# GNU Screen: «unknown command 'vert_split'» though C-a | works

Tags: gnu-screen

in GNU-screen (4.00.03jw4 FAU 2-May-06) I'm able to perform a vertical split pressing C-a | (i.e. Ctrl+a, then pipe).
Since I'd like to have the screen vertically splitted at the program startup, I put "vert_split" in my .screenrc file, but when I start it I can read «unknown command 'vert_split'» for few seconds in the status bar, and the screen is indeed not splitted. I can't find a solution for this in the manual.
Can someone please help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try 'split -v' instead; or C-a | (pipe).  The vert_split is in patch for screen and in some later releases.  Your release of screen (you didn't mention which) does not seem to have the command.  On a UNIX/Linux box, run 'info screen region split' or 'man screen' and search for '-v'.

Comment: Thank you, that is the right command. Anyway the feature is undocumented in both sources you mentioned (I don't know why), still it is reported in "Screen key bindings" (Ctrl-a ?) at the very end.